# Why can't I see the previous command with the up and down key?

Tags: pipenv, pyenv

Why can't I see the previous command with the up and down keys when using the terminal in a virtual environment using pyenv and pipenv?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in some terminals on Windows, but the corresponding issue was closed for some reason, even though people still encounter this issue:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/876